# Magento. OnBlockToHtml Before-After

Tags: magento

In magento there are 2 events:

core_block_abstract_to_html_before
core_block_abstract_to_html_after

They are called every time when toHtml method is called. What I want is to echo to output some valuable data, BUT I get following error:

```
HEADERS ALREADY SENT
```

So is there any way to append to output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the events being fired, the first event (`core_block_abstract_to_html_before`) receives the block instance as a parameter. The second event (`core_block_abstract_to_html_after`) receives both the block and the transport object from which you can extract the rendered content (this is the major feature of that transport object, as the rendered string is a local variable to the method otherwise). You can see the transport object receiving the rendered string in the line immediately preceding the dispatching of the second event:

```
self::$_transportObject->setHtml($html);
```

How you add to the block output depends on what you are trying to do. If you need to wrap your output *and* your preamble *needs* to use the `..._before` event, you should set a param on the block in that event's observer in your module, e.g.

```
public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore($observer)
{
    $arg = 'Whatever you are doing';
    $observer->getBlock()->setYourCustomParam($arg); //e.g. using Magento setter method
}
```

Then, in your `...after` event observer, you can evaluate your custom param and prepend it to the output like so:

```
public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlAfter($observer)
{
    $argBefore = $observer->getBlock()->getYourCustomParam();
    $argAfter = 'Whatever you are doing afterwards';

    //get output from _toHtml()
    $normalOutput = $observer->getTransport()->getHtml();

    //change the output; assume that both args are strings for this ex....
    $observer->getTransport()->setHtml( $argBefore . $normalOutput . $argAfter )
}
```

That said, don't forget that you have a number of options at your disposal, including `$block->setFrameTag($open,$close)` which can be (somewhat hackishly) used to wrap whatever you want around block output.

A caveat regarding these approaches: the output that is being added will not be cached in the block html cache.

One thing I'd like to add as well is that if you need to target your rendering to specific scopes you can always use the full-action-name-automatic event from `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::renderLayout()` method (`Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_layout_render_before_'.$this->getFullActionName());`). You just use the same class to observe this event, invoke it as a singleton for all events, and set a flag.

And finally, a note on your "Headers already sent" error: typical Magento rendering uses a response object, and output should be added to that response object via `$response->appendBody('string');`.

Comment: $normalOutput = $observer->getTransport()->getHtml();
    $observer->getTransport()->setHtml( $argBefore . $normalOutput . $argAfter ); This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Voting -1. You posted very clear explanation regarding these two events. However you didn't answer the question. Which was **why when we use that event we are getting server error?**. Or even better **How can we solve it?**

Comment: From my side I can say that it's mostly specific case. In my magento there were an issue with config. There was an attempt to register singleton of non-existed model. Initially I thought that it refers to to usage of that event. Which can cause an issue because it calls too many times. And found that I'm not the only who has that error. And I thought that it refers somehow to insufficient memory or some server configuration. **benmarks**, I'm apologizing, I'd like to remove my downvote, as now I understand that there no magic with it. Can you edit your post somehow to unblock my vote?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the template that it is rendering. Or add another template file and call it from the template file that is rendering (after adding the new one to the layout file).

Comment: This is not a solution. I want to add data to EVERY template is rendered. If I change renderView function in core, than everything works fine. But the thing is that I don't want to touch core and model overwriting doesn't work in this particular case.